# regular expression usage with [word1][wor2]

Tags: regex

I have a pattern like `[word1][wor2]`. I want to replace to `{@link word2|word1}`, word1, word2 could be anything.

I am very bad on using regular expression. Could anyone help me use regular expression match the pattern and replace to new pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a little more info? What language are you using? Will it always be two words, or could it be any number of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]
Replace: {@link $2|$1}
```

### Demo

The uses the approach of capturing the two adjacent word in square brackets, and then replacing with the text you want.

Comment: awesome, it works perfectly.
Any suggestion on how to get familiar with regex? Any practice?

Comment: You should practice your skills.  Honestly, answering SO questions is a good way to learn.